# Non-exhaustive pattern matching issue

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I made a dummy function that takes in a list of two lists, as shown below:

```
# let rec test ([a;b]) = match [a;b] with
    [] -> []
  | h::t -> 
          if ((List.length h) > 0) then
              [List.hd a]
          else
              []
;;
```

And I get this warning in return:

```
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
[]
```

But in the function above, am I matching for `[]` in the first match of the match function?

The warning makes sense, because when I execute `test([]);;`, I get an error. I'm just not sure who to check for this case when I thought I was already doing it with the code above.

Comment: Why do you match on `[a; b]` and not just `l`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your patterns in the `match` expression *are* exhaustive, in fact they're more than exhaustive since the pattern `[]` will never be able to match the expression `[a;b]`.

What isn't exhaustive is your pattern in the function signature (`([a;b])`). You should replace that pattern with a plain parameter name and then match on that. So your could would look like this:

```
let rec test xs = match xs with
  ...
```

or alternatively you could just use `function` and not name the parameter at all:

```
let rec test = function
  ...
```

Comment: Oh I see. Then just use an if statement to check if the length of `xs` is two before doing pattern matching, right?

Comment: No you can just do another pattern matching in the branch since your elements are lists.